# Android Studio: Statement must be prepended with case label

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was trying to make my own calculator app in Android Studio, but recently I got an error 'Statement must be prepended with case label'. I made two doubles (one for the first number and the second for the second number). I have 16 buttons (0-9 + plus, minus, divide, multiply + clear and equals) For every button I have the following code in the MainActivity.java:

`Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);`

And for every button except 'Equals' I have:

```
 //Button 1 Event Handler
    button1.setOnClickListener(
            //Button 1 Interface
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                //Button 1 Callback Method
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView output = findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("1");
                }
            }
    ); ``
```

For the 'equals' I have the following code:

```
      buttonE.setOnClickListener(
               new Button.OnClickListener(){
                   public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView output = findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble2 = String.valueOf(tempDouble);{

                    switch (sign .equals("+")){
                        output.setText(tempDouble + tempDouble2);
                        break;
                    }
                    case (sign .equals("-")){
                        output.setText(tempDouble - tempDouble2);
                        break
                    }
                    case (sign .equals("X"));{
                        output.setText(tempDouble * tempDouble2);
                    }
                    case (sign .equals("/")){
                        if (tempDouble2 = 0){
                            //Cannot devide by zero
                            output.setText("X");
                        }
                        else {
                            output.setText(tempDouble / tempDouble2);
                        }
                    }

                    //Reset the Sign variable
                    sign = "";
                }
            }
    );
});
```

But I can't seem to get it working :|
Does someone know and could show what needs to be changed to make my code working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `switch` statement instead of a bunch of `if` and `else if` statements, you have to format it like this:

```
switch (sign) {
    case "+":
        output.setText(tempDouble + tempDouble2);
        break;

    case "-":
        output.setText(tempDouble - tempDouble2);
        break

    case "X":
        output.setText(tempDouble * tempDouble2);

    case "/":
        if (tempDouble2 = 0) {
            //Cannot devide by zero
            output.setText("X");
        } else {
            output.setText(tempDouble / tempDouble2);
        }
}
```

And you probably want a `break` in your `"X"` case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! It's almost working, but now I get the error: **Operator '-', '*', and '/' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String'. ** Does someone know how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Plopkoek sounds like `tempDouble` and/or `tempDouble2` are Strings, not numbers. You can use something like `Double.valueOf(tempDouble)` to get a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using switch-case incorrectly. Look at the [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) .
2. I'm assuming that you are trying to add a `String` with a `double`. That's wrong.